# Can't find icon for Bootstrap logo such as <i class="fab fa-bootstrap"></i>

Tags: bootstrap-4

Can anyone tell me where to find an icon for the bootstrap logo?

I have looked everywhere. I need the type of icon offered by font-awesome.

I'm currently using a similar resized jpg file i found but i am looking for something more along the lines of what is offered by fontawesome.com in the format of

Answer (score 0):

There is not a similar icon in Font-Awesome to the bootstrap logo found here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/assets/img/bootstrap-stack.png.

Comment: I'm currently using a similar resized jpg file i found but i am looking for something more along the lines of what is offered by https://fontawesome.com/ in the format of <i class="fab fa-react"></i>

Answer (score 0):

Font-Awesome doesn't have an icon for the bootstrap logo.

If you really want to use font-awesome instead of your image, you may be able to get by with:

```
<i class="fas fa-bold"></i>
```

This icon is for the letter B / bold. You could then use css to add a purple rounded rectangle outside it.

Bootstrap's own website uses an svg for the logo with this code:

```
<svg class="d-block" width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 612 612" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" focusable="false"><title>Bootstrap</title><path fill="currentColor" d="M510 8a94.3 94.3 0 0 1 94 94v408a94.3 94.3 0 0 1-94 94H102a94.3 94.3 0 0 1-94-94V102a94.3 94.3 0 0 1 94-94h408m0-8H102C45.9 0 0 45.9 0 102v408c0 56.1 45.9 102 102 102h408c56.1 0 102-45.9 102-102V102C612 45.9 566.1 0 510 0z"></path><path fill="currentColor" d="M196.77 471.5V154.43h124.15c54.27 0 91 31.64 91 79.1 0 33-24.17 63.72-54.71 69.21v1.76c43.07 5.49 70.75 35.82 70.75 78 0 55.81-40 89-107.45 89zm39.55-180.4h63.28c46.8 0 72.29-18.68 72.29-53 0-31.42-21.53-48.78-60-48.78h-75.57zm78.22 145.46c47.68 0 72.73-19.34 72.73-56s-25.93-55.37-76.46-55.37h-74.49v111.4z"></path></svg>
```

This could be another option if you want to use exactly the same logo.